# Stanford Parser tags

Tags: stanford-nlp

I just started using Stanford Parser but I do not understand the tags very well. This might be a stupid question to ask but can anyone tell me what does the SBARQ and SQ tags represent and where can I find a complete list for them? I know how the Penn Treebank looks like but these are slightly different.

```
Sentence: What is the highest waterfall in the United States ?

(ROOT
  (SBARQ
    (WHNP (WP What))
    (SQ (VBZ is)
      (NP
        (NP (DT the) (JJS highest) (NN waterfall))
        (PP (IN in)
          (NP (DT the) (NNP United) (NNPS States)))))
    (. ?)))
```

I have looked at Stanford Parser website and read a few of the journals listed there but there are no explanation of the tags mentioned earlier. I found a manual describing all the dependencies used but it doesn't explain what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I have been working with Stanford parser for identifying noun phrases. I have found that this parser has some problems (better say malfunctions) to identify noun phrases. I want to find those studies that have evaluated Stanford parser itself as a tool. But I do not know how to search for them (I mean what keywords to search for this kind of evaluations). If you know some literature on this issue please introduce to me.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[This reference](https://gist.github.com/nlothian/9240750) looks to have an extensive list - not sure if it is complete or not.

Specifically, it lists the ones you're asking about as:

```
SBARQ - Direct question introduced by a wh-word or a wh-phrase. Indirect 
        questions and relative clauses should be bracketed as SBAR, not SBARQ.
SQ    - Inverted yes/no question, or main clause of a wh-question, 
        following the wh-phrase in SBARQ.
```

Comment: Thank you. You've been a great help. More than you know. To be honest I had been searching for the past 2-3 weeks but I thought that it shouldn't be hard to find and I didn't want to bother anyone. I guess I was looking at the wrong places. Thank you once again!

Comment: Clause level tags. Learn more here: http://bulba.sdsu.edu/jeanette/thesis/PennTags.html

Comment: http://bulba.sdsu.edu/jeanette/thesis/PennTags.html appears to have gone offline. I've copied the infomation to https://gist.github.com/nlothian/9240750

Answer (score -1):

To see the entire list just print the tagIndex of the parser

```
    LexicalizedParser lp =  LexicalizedParser.loadModel();
    System.out.println(lp.tagIndex); // print the tag index
```